# Форматирование даты из одного формата в другой

Tags: c#, дата

Я забираю из dateTimePicker1 значение даты в формате  {01.04.2020 0:00:00} а мне необходимо получить - 
2020-04-01  Каким образом это сделать ?

Comment: [Convert.ToDateTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.convert.todatetime), только фигурные скобки нужно будет отрезать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте следующее решение:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```